# DB2 query ,throwing an error

Tags: db2

My DB2 query is throwing an error while executing it in DB2 visualizer

**DB2 Query :**
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EDH.WBS_ENTITY (IN column_names varchar(2000), 
IN filter_by varchar(2000), IN LIMIT_VALUE INT, IN OFFSET_VALUE INT)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN
 DECLARE v_dynamicSql varchar(2000);
END ;

**Error**

[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "micSql varchar(2000)".  Expected tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.22.29

Answer (score 0):

This is a FAQ.

Ensure that you configure your dbvis with an alternative statement-delimiter(terminator) , and then use that special delimiter at the end of the procedure. Db2 needs to know the difference between the delimiters used inside the sproc, as distinct from the delimiter that ends the 'create procedure' statement.

dbvis also has the @delimiter command to let you specify this. Refer to the dbvis documentation for details.

For IBM data studio, see [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS62YD_2.2.1/com.ibm.datatools.sqlxeditor.doc/topics/tchngstmtterm.html), or refer to its online documentation.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this setting either in DB visualizer or IBM Data Studio